# use of join() in code line

Tags: javascript, ejs

Following code block needs a small syntax tweaking.

What I need is a `/` between `title` and `headline`. That bit is `ejs` code.

```
<div class="go-here"></div>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://example.com/embed.js"
data-target=".go-here"
data-slug="<%= [post.title,post.headline] %>">
</script>
```

Following all unsuccessful:

```html
data-slug="<%= [post.title,post.headline].join('/') %>"
data-slug="<%= [post.title,'/',post.headline] %>"
data-slug="<%= [post.title + '/' + post.headline] %>"
```

How to put it in `/` in between `title` and `headline` successfully????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```html
 <% var slug =['title','headline']%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com/embed.js" data-target=".go-here" data-slug="<%= slug.join('/')%>"></script>
```